# Как объединить два WireGuard конфига в один на клиенте?

Tags: wireguard

Есть 2 конфига WireGuard: один для "туда" (chatGPT) другой рабочий. На рабочий GPT ругается типа "русский".

конфиг "туда" естественно не видит работу.

есть возможность их объединить  на уровне файла без покупки Microtik?

```
# wg1 GPT
[Interface]
PrivateKey = key1_wg1
Address = address_wg1
DNS = 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey =  key2_wg1
PresharedKey = key3_wg1
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = address_wg1:порт


# wg2 Work
[Interface]
PrivateKey = key1_wg2
Address = address_wg2

[Peer]
PublicKey = key2_wg2
AllowedIPs = 10.255.254.1/32, 10.0.0.0/22
Endpoint = address:port wg2
PersistentKeepalive = 10
```